# CodeIgniter - Selecting from database by another query's result

Tags: php, codeigniter

Forgive me if it is asked before, but i couldn't find the relevant keyword to search. I will try to explain my problem.

I have DB tables named "ilan" and "places". In "ilan" table, there are 3 columns which holds IDs of places - city, district, street.

And I want to learn what to do to print ilan.name and related places.name in the view.

I have a controller like:

```
class Estate_control extends CI_Controller{

public function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();   
}

function index(){

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model("estate_model");

    $data['tum_bayiler'] = $this->estate_model->tum_bayileri_listele();
    $data['sonEmlaklar'] = $this->estate_model->sonEmlaklar();      

    $this->load->view("index",$data);

}
}
```

I have model like:

```
class Estate_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
}

function sonEmlaklar(){
    $query = $this->db
            ->select()
    ->from("ilan")
    ->order_by("gunceltarih DESC")
    ->limit(36)
    ->get();

    return $query->result();            
}

}
```

My DB tables:

ilan:

ilan_id, gunceltarih, ... , ilan_city(an ID in places table), ilan_district(an ID in places table), ilan_street(an ID in places table), ...

places:

places_id, places_name, ...

Any ideas on what to do to print ilan.name and **related places.name** in the view.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: do you have a column name = gunceltarih?

Comment: @jcho360 yes, it holds the date of update.

Comment: use a join `$this->db->join()`

Comment: @Mike i think "join" won't work for me. I have 3 columns related with "places". So I have to make 3 queries for each "ilan" row?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the relevant part of the code

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select("ilan.*, places.name")
->from("ilan")
->join('places', 'places.id = ilan.ilan_city OR places.id = ilan.ilan_district OR places.id =ilan.ilan_street')
->order_by("gunceltarih DESC")
->limit(36)
->get();
```

Comment: "Join" does not fit my situation because I have 3 columns relates with "places". I think I have to make a new query for each "ilan" row. But I couldn't find the way

Comment: I know you have 3 columns, that's why you use the OR conditions (or AND if you need the 3 of them to be equal), please post an example of the tables and the result you want, if you need a very specific kind of query you will need to write the SQL yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out. I don't know how efficient it is but it works for me.

I created a function inside index function in my controller as follows:

```
function index(){

    //whatever here

function getPlace($e){
    $ci = get_instance(); //to get properties of parent class
    $query = $ci->estate_model->ilanSehir($e);


    return $query;
}   

    //whatever here

}
```

Then I put a function inside my model as follows:

```
function ilanSehir($e){ 
$query = $this->db->select("*")
    ->from("places")
    ->where("places_id",$e)
    ->get();
 return $query->row();    //This will return one row so it must be row() instead of result()
```

}

And in my view I called the function with the parameter I want:

```
<?php $place = getPlace($ilan->ilan_city);
      echo $place->places_name;
?>
```

As I said before, **I don't know how efficient it is but it worked for me**. Hope it helps. If I'm wrong somewhere, please warn me.

Thank you all who answered